# Test with Jest (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I cannot execute the following test, what is the problem?

```js
test('3 - shorthand syntax', function () {
    const name = 'Myamoto';
    const age = 32;
    const samurai = { name, age };
    expect(samurai).toEqual(age: 32, name: "Myamoto");
  });
```

Comment: `.toEqual(age: 32, name: "Myamoto");` is invalid syntax... an argument list is not an object...

Comment: I can do:  expect(samurai).toEqual(samurai); but I guess that it is not the way to  pass an object?

Comment: You might consider figuring out basic JS syntax rules before diving into Jest, might be a bit easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should pass and object to the `toEqual()` method, to compare to the `Object` that you've created.

```
expect(samurai).toEqual({age: 32, name: "Myamoto"});
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how that is actually done, I am a bit confused...
expect(samurai).toEqual(Object); ??

Comment: No. the `toEqual()` method compares the data passed to `expect()`, and see if they're equivalent. In this case, the both should be of the type `Object`, because the first is an object.

Comment: That means... expect(samurai).toEqual(samurai); (?) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alejandro, that's not the right way to use jest. You should pass the `samurai` to a function, and pass the function call to the `expect()`, like `expect(myFunc(samurai)).toEqual({age: 32, name: "Myamoto"});`. Then, jest will compare if the result of your function is equivalent to what it should be.

Comment: I got it now! I was not able to see the {} problem... Thanks Matheus!